# android moving multiple circle on a L shaped path

Tags: java, android, animation

would try to move multiple points along an L shaped path to simulate water flow from a point to another. I created a view that allow to create a single point and created an animation. Now I'm stuck as I cannot understand how to retrieve values from the animator add points to it and update animation. Can someone try to move me on right path?

public class FlowAnimation extends View implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

```
int radius = 20;
int color = Color.WHITE;
Paint paint = null;
private ValueAnimator mAnimator;
PathMeasure pm;
float point[] = {0f, 0f};
Path path;



public FlowAnimation(Context context) {
    super(context);
    paint = new Paint();
    path = new Path();

    path.lineTo(100,150);
    path.lineTo(300,500);
    path.close();
}

public FlowAnimation(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint = new Paint();
}

public FlowAnimation(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

public FlowAnimation(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int x = getWidth();
    int y = getHeight();
    paint.setColor(this.color);
    canvas.drawCircle(x / 2, y / 2, this.radius, paint);

}


public void startAnim() {
    // sets the range of our value
    mAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 180);
    // sets the duration of our animation
    mAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    // registers our AnimatorUpdateListener
    mAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
    mAnimator.start();
}


@Override
public void onAnimationUpdate(@NonNull ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {

    //gets the current value of our animation
    int value = (int) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();




}
```

}